# When UFD implies PID

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

The following result is too elementary, both to state and to prove, not to be known.  Can someone give a reference?  Is there any hope if you don't suppose UFD (i.e. move that from the hypothesis to the conclusion)?

Theorem.  Let $R$ be a commutative UFD with field of fractions $F$.  Suppose that for any subring $S$ of $F$ that properly includes $R$, there is some non-unit of $R$ that becomes invertible in $S$.  Then $R$ is a PID.

Comment: If you remove UFD from the hypothesis, then it is satisfied by every Bezout domain. So, no, you can't remove it.

Comment: Any chance you could make that comment an answer?

Comment: @George: The distinction PID vs Bézout is only in noetheriannes, right So MO's question may be changed by replacing "UFD" with "noetherian domain". Right?